# Not able to get featured image when post created through wordpress Rest API

Tags: image, wordpress-rest-api, action-hook

Creating post through wordpress rest api and to set featured image I passed featured media as parameter and post is created and thumbnail id is set in database but get_post_meta doesn't return thumbnail id
get_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id');

returning empty .

Can anyone help

Tried get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'thumbnail') to get featured image but no result and
$image_id = get_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id');
wp_get_attachment_url($image_id) but no results.Can anyone help what other possible solutions I can try